# Android Bluetooth - detect a disconnection from a device

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I am trying to catch a bluetooth device disconnection intent filter.
I added a log to the onReceive but it never reaches it and is not displayed in the logcat.
I suspect that the problem is with my manifest.xml configuration:

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.company.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".BTActivity"
            android:label="BTActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("got-in", "got-in-");
        // String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        Log.i("disconnect", device.getName());
        Intent i = new Intent(context, BTActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("deviceName", device.getName());
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your id to your next Intent
        context.startActivity(i);
        // finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this code for receiving a disconnect (when Bluetooth is still turned on):

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also you have to register a service that then registers a broadcast receiver for Bluetooth status change, so your app knows when Bluetooth was turned off and therefore discards all active devices, as you won't receive a ACL_DISCONNECT when Bluetooth is simply turned off.

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(bluetoothTurnedOnOff, filter);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothTurnedOnOff = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
 [...]
```

Comment: WHy do I have to create a service? Isnt it enough having a receiver declared in my manifest xml file and a class that extends BroadcastReceiver? should not this be enough?

Comment: You have to create a service because the Intent `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` cannot be registered through the manifest, therefore you have to create a service that registers a custom Receiver

Answer (score 3):

For new users. it will works . Your manifest file looks

```
<receiver android:name="(package name).BluetoothReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and your receiver will look like

```
else if (intent.getAction().equals(`enter code here`
    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
    // connection lost
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `<category .../>` from the intent-filter and try again.

Comment: Tried this as well, but again it does not enter into the onreceive callback function. what am I missing? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED action in intent filter. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope. It still the same. My guess is that my manifest is not correct. but I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Infact even the "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED" does not work....