# Android Bluetooth -- how to "Undiscover" devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I'm fairly new to Android and am creating a bluetooth-enabled app.  Following this very helpful doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

In it they provide a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND which reports any discovered devices, shown below.  It works well.

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // When discovery finds a device
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
}
};
```

My question is, how can I detect when a discovered device *goes away* (eg powers down or goes out of range)?  I'm trying to present an active/dynamic list to the user, and I have to take items away when these events happen.

I tried to add an additional action to my intent filter as follows.

```
            IntentFilter intent_filter = new IntentFilter();
            intent_filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            intent_filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_DISAPPEARED);
            ptr_OwnerActivity.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intent_filter);
            return true;
```

But the weird thing is that ACTION_DISAPPEARED seems to not be defined... which is odd because it is RIGHT NEXT to the 'ACTION_FOUND' definition in BluetoothDevice.java.

```
/**
 * Broadcast Action: Remote device disappeared.
 * <p>Sent when a remote device that was found in the last discovery is not
 * found in the current discovery.
 * <p>Always contains the extra field {@link #EXTRA_DEVICE}.
 * <p>Requires {@link android.Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH} to receive.
 * @hide
 */

  @SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
    public static final String ACTION_DISAPPEARED =
        "android.bluetooth.device.action.DISAPPEARED";
```

Which looks like exactly what I need -- so weird that its undefined to my class.  But when I ignore that it is undefined and copy that string definition to my class, just so I can add it to my filter, the BroadcastReceiver seems not to trap any additional events when I power off my discovered device.

So... it feels like I'm doing this wrong. :)  Does anyone know a good way to trap the fact that a discovered device is no longer discovered, for the purpose of updating a dynamic list?

Thanks for any thoughts/help.

Comment: As of 9/15/17 this appears to still be an issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Good to know that the `"android.bluetooth.device.action.DISAPPEARED"` string doesn't work. I found this answer [13147653](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147653/android-bluetooth-detect-a-disconnection-from-a-device) that discusses a different approach to getting a disconnect broadcast.